# Set widget width based on its height

Tags: python, pyside

I am trying to find a way to have one of my widgets maintain a width based on its height. I have other widgets working fine reimplementing the **heightForWidth** method. That was easy because that method is standard. I know there is no included **widthForHeight** method so I have tried many options the internet has suggested but have not gotten anything to work all the way. What I currently have almost gets me there.

I first reimplement my widget's sizeHint to get its width to be a ratio of its parent's (QHBoxLayout) height.

The sizeHint makes MyCustomLabel show with the right size at first show but did not update during times the user resized the window. I don't know if this the best way but to fix that I am reimplementing resizeEvent and calling adjustSize to force the sizeHint recalculation.

With those two reimplemented methods MyCustomLabel shows with the right size. I placed this custom widget in a QHBoxLayout with a few other standard widgets. The problem is the other widgets in the layout don't respect the new size of my MyCustomLabel when the user resizes the window. What I end up with is the other widgets in the layout either overlapping or being placed too far from MyCustomLabel. I kind of get it, I am brute forcing my widget to a size and not letting the layout do the work. However I thought updating the sizeHint would inform the layout of MyCustomLabel's new size and adjust everything accordingly. How do I fix this layout problem or am I going about this widthForHeight problem all the wrong way?

**Edit:**
I tried @AlexanderVX suggestion of setting the SizePolicy to Minimum and while it does prevent the other widgets from overlapping it also locked MyCustomLabel to a fixed size. I need the widget to expand and shrink with the layout. I also tried Preferred, Expanding, MinimumExpanding policies just to see if they would do anything but with no luck.

```
from __future__ import division
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
import sys    


class MyCustomLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.Signal(int)
    dblClicked = QtCore.Signal(int)    

    def __init__(self, leadSide='height', parent=None):
        super(MyCustomLabel, self).__init__()
        self.leadSide = leadSide    

        # sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
        #         QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        # sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
        #         QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, 
        #         QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        # sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        #         QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        # self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)    

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(MyCustomLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.adjustSize()    

    def sizeHint(self):
        super(MyCustomLabel, self).sizeHint()
        parentSize = self.parent().size().toTuple()
        if self.leadSide.lower() == 'height':
            new_size = QtCore.QSize(parentSize[1] * (16 / 9), parentSize[1]) * .9
        if self.leadSide.lower() == 'width':
            new_size = QtCore.QSize(parentSize[0], parentSize[0] / (16 / 9)) * .9    

        return new_size    


class __Test__(QtGui.QWidget):    

    def __init__(self):
        super(__Test__, self).__init__()    

        self.initUI()    

    def initUI(self):
        customLabel = MyCustomLabel(leadSide='height')
        # customLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        customLabel.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;' 
            'border:2px solid red;')    

        btn01 = QtGui.QPushButton('button')
        btn01.setFixedHeight(80)    

        textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        textEdit.setFixedSize(150, 150)    

        layout01 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout01.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout01.setSpacing(0)
        layout01.addWidget(customLabel)
        layout01.addWidget(btn01)
        layout01.addWidget(textEdit)
        self.setLayout(layout01)    

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Testing')
        self.show()    


def main():    

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = __Test__()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The question is more of layout behavior and you should consider sizing policy: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum as well. My guess is that setting size policy for that label as `label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum)` should help. I am unsure of how exactly to write that in Pyton.

Comment: @AlexanderVX in python: `label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)` :P

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexanderVX. I tried Minimum but that did not help me. It just locked the widget to a fixed size. I edited the question to show what I tried.

Comment: @Andrew You could publish a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ie a code that can be executed directly, it is boring to try to put everything together to test the code.

Comment: BTW, `new_size = QtCore.QSize(pSize[1] * (1.77777), pSize[1])` may try to specify the width more than the parent's by multiplying its height to that value. And the layout is horizontal box which is usually for placing more than one item horizontally. Unsure of correctness of all that. I see you try to maintain 16/9 ratio for some reason.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated my question with a complete code sample.